# Can't figure out this NSDateComponents error

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have the following statements:

```
NSDate *Today = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
NSDate  *cDate =  [Lines objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger) 0];
NSLog(@"cDate: %@  Today: %@", cDate, Today); 
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSInteger desiredComponents = (NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit);
NSDateComponents *secondComponents = [calendar components:desiredComponents fromDate:Today];
NSDateComponents *firstComponents  = [calendar components:desiredComponents fromDate:cDate];
```

NSLog statement prints:cDate: 2011-08-16 18:35:29 +0000  Today: 2011-08-17 15:53:19 +0000

The last statement (firstComponents) which is very similar to the previous statement(secondComponents) crashes with the following error:
unrecognized selector sent to instance

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Make sure cDate is actually an instance of `NSDate`. `NSLog(@"cDate class: %@", [cDate class]);`

Comment: What selector did the message say WAS received??  And by an instance of what class??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if `cDate` really is an instance of `NSDate`. It could also be for example an `NSString` instance with the value "2011-08-16 18:35:29 +0000".

Comment: Doesn't the statement: NSDate  *cDate =  [Lines objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger) 0];  define cDate as a NSDate?

Comment: No, it just tells the compiler that you expect it to be an NSDate, but the return type of objectAtIndex: is id, which means it can be anything.